# Codeigniter - CSS

Tags: php, codeigniter

i spend my hours to solve this problem but cannot reach anything.I applied what said in stackoverflow but it does not work.

As you see  below my css files are stores in public directory and try to use anasayfa.css

[image]

and try to reach my css files with my view. but does not work.
[image]

i also remove my index.php with htaccess my in rule in htaccess 
i allowed css files like that

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pasaj/index.php/$1 [L]
```

How can i reach my css ? what's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's the "Pasaj - El emegi.." ? Is it the page title? why is there inside an url?

It should be (absoluth url):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/css/anasayfa/anasayfa.css"/>
```

Or, much easier, using `base_url()` (url helper):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>public/css/anasayfa....">
```

Or with `link_tag()` (html helper):

```
<?php echo link_tag('public/css/anasayfa...');?>
```

**UPDATE:**

to load an helper, put inside the controller's method you're using to call that view:

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

Refer to the [manual](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html) for this and other basic infos: it's pretty extensive and clear, it will answer many of your doubts

Comment: Be sure you load/autoload urlhelper if you use it in a link tag like that as many browsers wont print any sensible error information if you forgot to load the helper.

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>public/css/anasayfa/anasayfa.css"> i put this.The result is empty page..

Answer (score 1):

you are using relative URLs. the base url of CodeIgniter is `mysite.com/index.php`. so that means your `<link>` is looking for it in `mysite.com/index.php/views/public/css...` - it treats it like another page, with `views` as controller, `public` as method and the rest as parameters.

the shortcut method is to prepend a `/` to your link url (to tell it to start from the root)

the longcut method is to prepend [base_url()](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html) to your view/template before it is passed on to the browser for rendering

Comment: I won't downvote but a bit wrong information here. Base url is the url which you define in config page. In most cases, it is better to leave it as mysite.com. Hence, its not necessarily will output mysite.com/index.php. What you mentioned is actually the site url(which again can be configured).

Comment: i actually meant base_url. *This function returns the same thing as site_url, without the **index_page or url_suffix being appended*** - which means it's like starting off from root

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS files SHOULD NOT BE in your views folder, never.

That said from what I see they are not, they are in a public folder at the root ?

So then you need to change your link to

> /public/css/...

in place of

> /views/public/css/...